# Python help: finding repeats

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, repeat

I have these functions below where I am placing the letter "b" at a certain location within a matrix. (I'm making minesweeper and these "b" represents where the bomb is located in the matrix). I must put 'z' bombs into the function, but where the bombs are placed cannot occur more than once. I know how to place them inside the function, but finding if they are repeating is what I can't figure out

```
from random import*

mat1 = []
mat2 = []
def makemat(x):
    for y in range(x):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for z in range(x):
            list1.append(0)
            list2.append("-")
        mat1.append(list1)
        mat2.append(list2)
makemat(2)

def printmat(mat):
    for a in range(len(mat)):
        for b in range(len(mat)):
            print(str(mat[a][b]) + "\t",end="")  
        print("\t")

def addmines(z):
    for a in range(z):
        x = randrange(0,len(mat1))
        y = randrange(0,len(mat1))   
        mat1[y][x] = "b"            
addmines(4)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a fair question, but you should describe your problem in the actual body of the question, not just the title (I think this is why you are being down-voted).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but why not just check whether "b" is already there?

```
def addmines(z):
for a in range(z):
    x = randrange(0,len(mat1))
    y = randrange(0,len(mat1))
    if mat1[y][x] == "b":
        addmines(1)
    else:
        mat1[y][x] = "b"
addmines(4)
```

Comment: If the grid is completely filled with mines, you'll get a `RuntimeError` because you recursed too far.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I am looking for. But when doing it, it reprints the matrix over and over until finally mat[y][x] != "b"

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is sample without replacement.  Try using [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.sample)

```
import random

...

def addmines(countMines):
    countRows = len(mat1)
    countCols = len(mat1[0])
    countCells = countRows * countCols

    indices = random.sample(range(countCells), countMines)

    rowColIndices = [(i // countRows, i % countRows) for i in indices]

    for rowIndex, colIndex in rowColIndices:
        mat1[rowIndex][colIndex] = 'b'
```